# How to use for-each loop when inserting arrays into mysql using Codeigniter?

Tags: mysql, codeigniter, foreach

Im trying to add dtnamic fileds and through that insert arrays data into mysql but when i try this code nothing error and ref no only inserting  can anyone help me . im using Codeigniter framework.

This is my view page : [my form with js](http://jsfiddle.net/Pravin_com/pxmfyLk9/#&togetherjs=L6T8g1E1a1)

```
<div id="invoice_form">
        <?php echo form_open(base_url().'sample/myinvoice'); ?>
        <div><?php echo form_input(array('id'=>'ref','name'=>'ref'));?></div>
            <div  id="description"><p id="add_field">ADD DESCRIPTION</p></div>
        <input id="btn_add" name="btn_add" type="submit" class="btn btn-primary" value="Save" />
        <?php echo form_close(); ?>
        </div>
```

This is my Controller :

```
function myinvoice()
    {
        $this->load->library('form_validation');

        $this->form_validation->set_rules('ref', 'REFERENCE NO', 'trim');
        $this->form_validation->set_rules('description', 'DESCRIPTIONS', 'trim'); 
        $this->form_validation->set_rules('voucher_no', 'DESCRIPTIONS', 'trim'); 
        $this->form_validation->set_rules('price', 'DESCRIPTIONS', 'trim'); 

        if($this->form_validation->run())
        {
            $this->load->database();
            $this->load->model('sample_model');

            $ref =  $this->input->post('ref');
            $description = $this->input->post('description');
            $voucher_no = $this->input->post('voucher_no');
            $price = $this->input->post('price');
             $i = 0;
             if($description){
            foreach($description as $row){
            $data['ref_no'] = $ref[$i];
            $data['descriptions'] = $description[$i];
            $data['voucher'] = $voucher_no[$i];
            $data['value'] = $price[$i];
             $this->db->insert("description",$data);
            $i++; }}
        }else{
            echo "form validation error";}}
```

Comment: possible duplicate of [How to Insert Arrays (Multiple rows) into Mysql using Codeigniter?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/31807009/how-to-insert-arrays-multiple-rows-into-mysql-using-codeigniter)

Comment: that is 3 table this is only one table but same thing i want insert can u help me

Comment: chek below me and Santy conversation plz

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This is the answer i hope this will help to many people :)

This is my view Page:

```
    <div id="invoice_form">
    <?php echo form_open(base_url().'sample/myinvoice'); ?>
    <div><?php echo form_input(array('id'=>'ref','name'=>'ref'));?></div>
    <div  id="description"><p id="add_field">ADD DESCRIPTION</p></div>
    <input id="btn_add" name="btn_add" type="submit" class="btn btn-primary" value="Save" />
    <?php echo form_close(); ?>
    </div>
    <script>
    var count = 0;
    $(document).ready(function() {
    $('p#add_field').click(function(){
       count += 1;
       var html='<strong>Description  '+ count +'</strong>'+'<input id="description'+ count +'"name="description[]'+'" type="text" />'+'<input id="description'+ count +'"name="voucher_no[]'+'" type="text" />'+'<input id="description'+ count +'"name="price[]'+'" type="text" /><br />';
       $('#description').append(html); });
       });
    </script>
```

This is My Controller :

```
function myinvoice()
    {
        $this->load->library('form_validation');

        $this->form_validation->set_rules('ref', 'REFERENCE NO', 'trim');
        $this->form_validation->set_rules('description[]', 'DESCRIPTIONS', 'trim'); 
        $this->form_validation->set_rules('voucher_no[]', 'DESCRIPTIONS', 'trim'); 
        $this->form_validation->set_rules('price[]', 'DESCRIPTIONS', 'trim'); 

        if($this->form_validation->run())
        {
            $this->load->database();
            $this->load->model('sample_model');

            $ref =  $this->input->post('ref');
            $description = $this->input->post('description');
            $voucher_no = $this->input->post('voucher_no');
            $price = $this->input->post('price');
             $i = 0;
             if($description){
            foreach($description as $row)
            {
            $data['ref_no'] = $ref;
            $data['descriptions'] = $description[$i];
            $data['voucher'] = $voucher_no[$i];
            $data['value'] = $price[$i];
             $this->db->insert("description",$data);
            $i++;
            }}
            }else{
            print_r(validation_errors());
            }}
```